# Can someone explain this switch statement behavior?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Why does this,

```
public class Bar 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int i = 1;

        switch(i)
        {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Case 2 being executed");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

output this,

> Case 2 being executed

?

How is it even possible to enter the case block for an input value of `2` when the input value is explicitly `1`? Note that I'm aware I can avoid this behavior by adding a `break` statement in the case block for 1.

Comment: It's called `fall-through`.

Comment: Because ... that's how `switch` works? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html note the second example. FYI `case` statements aren't blocks (as far as the language is concerned) they're simply labels inside the switch block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How is it even possible to enter the case block for an input value of
>   2 when the input value is explicitly 1?

This behaviour is called *fall-through* which is quite common mistake with beginners working with `switch-case`. Actually, `case 1:` does execute first. But, since there is no `break` statement in *case 1*, your `switch-case` goes onto executing the next cases, until it finds a `break` statement. So, it will even execute the code for `case 2:` and hence the output. And then it breaks after executing `case 2`, as it encounters a break.

So, change your `swich-case` to: -

```
switch(i)
{
        case 0: break;
        case 1: break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Case 2 being executed");
            break;
        default:
            break;
}
```

to see the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't put a break after case 1 so it uses case 2's logic. You need a break statement after every case or the compiler will just go down to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

The switch statement will run through all case blocks until it reaches the first break or the end of the switch statement.

So, in your case it executes all blocks until it reaches the break in the second block.

If there were any statements in the "0" and the "1" block, these would also be executed.

This behaviour can also be really useful.